# Axios onUploadProgress jumps at 100% even before the request is done

Tags: api, axios, async-onprogressupdate

I have a controller that calls multiple external api from `Gmail API` concurrently, and then saves the retrieved data into the database, all of this in ONE post request.

To start, I pooled the external api requests, map the results and save it to db.

In my Controller:

```
$resp = Http::pool(fn (Pool $pool) [
            $pool->as('pool-1')->withToken($user->token)->get('https://....call-1');
            $pool->as('pool-2')->withToken($user->token)->get('https://....call-2');
            $pool->as('pool-3')->withToken($user->token)->get('https://....call-3');
        ]);

collect($resp)->map(function ($req) {

    Email::firstOrCreate(...);
})
```

In my vue component:

```
const config = {
            onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
                    console.log(`sent: ${Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)}`)
                }
        }

axios.post(url, param, config).then(response => {}).catch(err => {})
```

Now, when I check in console.

It should be logging:

```
sent:0
sent:1
sent:2
...
sent:100
```

But instead, it automatically logs `sent:100` even though the post request is still pending.

Is this a bug in chrome? or axios?, or perhaps it has something to do with external api calls?

Or if it isn't, can someone point out where I went wrong?

Comment: Are you running your backend on localhost?

Comment: @tbhaxor I tried running on localhost and staging server. still the same.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce the same with throttled connection? Try with Slow 3G. For ref, [check this out](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/639#issuecomment-627338742)